# Getting errors while changing Chart framework from Swift 2.+ to Swift 3.0 version

Tags: ios, swift, charts, swift3, swift2

I am trying to change CHART(https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) swift version 2.3 to 3.0 library in previous project.

After removing old files (Swift 2.+) files from project added new files latest version (Swift 3.0).

I am getting error like:

> /Users/mac/Documents/Project/Your Notes/Your
>   Notes/Classes/Common/Utilities/RadarGraph/Utils/ChartFill.swift:21:17:
>   Type member may not be named 'Type', since it would conflict with the
>   'foo.Type' expression

I searched lot of time regarding this. I am unable to get the exact thing.

Comment: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1072, thats bcoz of the keyword **Type** as used instance

Comment: @KumarKL,

Can you please guide what change i need to be make. I am not getting exactly.

Comment: u might ve used 'Type' as declared instance in somewhere ChartFill.swift.
Seems like Type is reserved word . So use different name  or as suggested here<https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1072> use backticks to escape it.